# Magento Java Soap Gzip Compression

Tags: java, magento, soap

I tried to compress the communication channel between a soap client and magento :

public static MageApiModelServerWsiHandlerPortType getInstance() {

```
    Client client = null;

    if (instance == null) {
        try {
            logger = Logger.getLogger(SoapClient.class);
            Properties properties = Property.getInstance(PropertyType.Application);
            String url = properties.getProperty("magUrl");

            if (url != null) {
                //logger.info("Creating service...");
                MagentoService service = new MagentoService(new URL(url));
                //logger.info("Calling port...");
                instance = service.getMageApiModelServerWsiHandlerPort();

                client = ClientProxy.getClient(instance);

                HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
                HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
                httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
                httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(36000);

                http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

                client.getInInterceptors().add(new GZIPInInterceptor());
                client.getOutInterceptors().add(new GZIPOutInterceptor());
        ...
```

which works fine for calling various types of data. But when it comes to creating a product, the sender (magento) returns following error:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Invalid XML
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)
    at $Proxy33.catalogProductCreate(Unknown Source)
    at at.magento.service.SoapService.createProductOnly(SoapService.java:280)
    at at.magento.ready.SoapProductTest.testCreateProduct(SoapProductTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Invalid XML
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:75)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1667)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1428)
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.close(DeflaterOutputStream.java:143)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.close(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.close(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:195)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:658)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:532)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:464)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:367)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: does it work without compression?

Comment: why not handle this with mod_deflate? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html

Comment: hi! i did that in the .htaccess of the magento's root!